# A "clean"(er) bookdown install

Tags: r, knitr, bookdown

The wonderful bookdown example drops all its bits and pieces into the project root directory (for an Rstudio project), and leaves a variety of files there.  I know I can move the Rmd files to subfolders, and I know I can direct the output elsewhere, but there are still several  .css files, .sh files (these look entirely optional) the (essential) _bookdown.yml file.

Ideally I'd want to "just" have a "report" folder in the project root, and leave the Rmd files, the outputs, and all the subsidiary files somewhere lower down in the folder structure within a project.

How far can I do in this pursuit? Recommendations? I'd welcome suggestions. Thanks,

Comment: This question would benefit from a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) with sample input that can be used for testing and clear description of the problematic files.

Comment: Fair enough: ... Of the files found here: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo which can be moved to subfolders and which must remain in the root folder of a project?